what is the difference between a page, view and components in vue
where as an example we have a router and there I have my pages. but no components or views.
I am having trouble identifying in where to put my components or views.

I now that in my components we put the reusuable code
then when do I add a view?


You may check the following tutorial form laracasts: link

"as an example" - what example? It could be what the answer describes, or something else. "Page" is ambiguous. There are pages in MPA, and the "pages" term is used for separate apps in Vue CLI, and it could be something else. This depends on the context. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

In short, there is no difference.

In more detail, Vue router's <RouterView /> accepts any Vue component as "View" (root component for that route).
Placing those components inside a separate folder is a non-mandatory convention, to have them separated from the other @/components, so they are easier to find while developing and also recognizable by scripts (sometimes they're served differently than normal components - SSR and/or async components).
If you don't like this convention, don't use it.
However, since it's included in the default template, you'll end up having to delete /views in each new project you make, and modify router code accordingly. So it's slightly more work for you, in the long run.

On a separate note, it's not clear what you refer to when you say "Page". Sometimes it's used as a synonym of "View" which, in the context of a Vue app, is a short name for "the root component loaded by <RouterView /> on a given route".
If you use "Page" here as something other than an alias for "View", please clarify.

Just to add uncertainty, there can be nested views in a router, while a page usually stands for top-level view
